# SharePoint 2016 Content Organizer

Tags: 2016, content-organizer

Currently administering a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 front end servers prioritising traffic via a load balancer.

Can anyone with SharePoint 2016 knowledge advise me as to whether SharePoint 2016 has a content organiser (or similar file shunting tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Content Organizer feature has not been depricated, and the Documention also indicates that it applies for Sharepoint 2016, [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-the-content-organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a)